# Changing sequence of JUnit gives random errors

Tags: spring, junit4, testcase

I have a set of JUnit test cases in various packages. When I put them together in a test suite in a sequence it passes all the test cases. However, when I change their sequence the ones that have @ContextConfiguration fail with application context errors.

I could analyse that they seem to be failing because of @BeforeClass method that I have defined in my test cases Since, it loads all the static method in a separate utility class for those test cases. But I am not able to analyze why just mere changing the sequence is fixing everything for me. Also, changing their sequence permanently wont help either as ideally the order in which they are being executed should not be a matter of concern as all should be independent. And we cant control on jenkins which test to execute first. Please help.

Comment: You're asking to help you with unknown caode causing unknown errors. That would be possible if we were extra-lucid wizards. But we're just programmers.

Comment: All right, I shall put some extra brain then and still get deeper into it to. I was wondering it could have been a general issue with other programmers too. Thanks for that.

Comment: Or you could post the code of two minimal tests that fail when run in a specific order, and the exception stack trace.

Comment: Exception says it fails to initialise a bean, and every time with a different bean as I change their sequence. Individual test cases also run successfully. And some fixed sequence patterns also run successfully. But changing those fixed sequence are making things worse for me. Probably I should spend some more time on that. May be I am heading for a wrong root cause. Thanks anyways.